# What permissions should each file under .ssh have?

Tags: ssh, permissions

What permissions should each file under .ssh have?  I just experienced some glitch caused by .ssh/config not having 600.  What permissions other files there should have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `man ssh_config`:

> ~/.ssh/config
>               This  is  the per-user configuration file.  The format of this file is described above.  This file is used by the SSH client.  Because of the
>               potential for abuse, this file must have strict permissions: read/write for the user, and not accessible by others.

Your private keys and your `authorized_keys` file should have the same (`600`) but your public keys can have a more permissive `644`.